# How can I get WP to use templates in lower-level subfolder?

Tags: templates

I want to add sub-directories to the 'page-templates' directory and thus be able to better-group associated files.

As WP won't normally read that deep, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you're correct in saying WP will only scan directories 1 level deep for templates, since 4.4 you have complete control over [the `theme_page_templates` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) (you can now add to as well as remove from the list):

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', function( $templates ) {
     $templates['page-templates/another/directory/template.php'] = 'Another Directory Template';

     return $templates;
});
```